# Find out minimum steps to reach any corner of maze?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, backtracking, maze

You have given a `n*m` maze (matrix) which contains values **0**, **1** and **2** . value **0** means cell is open , value **1** means cell is block and value **2** is starting point. You can go only in left ,right ,top ,down  direction in maze. Find out minimum distance from starting point to any corner of matrix .

**Example :** 
n = 4, m = 5
maze :

> 1 1 1 0 1
>  1 0 2 0 1
>  1 0 1 0 1
>  0 0 1 0 1

Answer will be 2 .
path -> starting point`(2 ,3)->(2,4)->(1,4).`

Help me to solve this problem !!

Comment: What have you learned? graph, Djikstra, shortest path?

Comment: just new in programming , I have just solved some basic problem related to graph(bfs ,dfs , mst) and also start learning backtracking .  question comes in mind while solving rate in maze problem.

Comment: So to solve this translate it to a graph, then use one of the algorithms that you have learned to find the shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `BFS` and already solved the following classic problem:

> Calculate the shortest path from a starting point to ending point in 2D
>   grid with some obstacles!

then you can solve your problem by running BFS from starting point once and then going through all corner points having value `0`  and comparing the minimum distance among them.

There can be several paths leading to minimum distance. If you want to trace the path then you can maintain another `2D` grid for storing parent's information of each `2D` point while performing `BFS`.

Please let me know if you face any problem while coding. Thanks!!